# python ete2 TreeNode check if it has attribute

Tags: python, python-2.7, tree, attributes, etetoolkit

I have a tree t which some of its nodes has an attribute 'a'
I want to test if a given node has this attribute, what I did is

```
if not n.a:
   print "no a "
```

but I'm getting an error treenode n has no attribute a

Any way to test it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just use the generic pythonic way

```
if not hasattr(node, "a"): 
   print "a attribute not found in node:", node
```

If "a" is registered as a regular feature in your [ETE tree](http://etetoolkit.org), you could also use the following approach:

```
from ete2 import Tree
t = Tree()
t.populate(5)
t.children[0].add_features(a = "My annotation")

for node in t.traverse():
    if "a" in node.features:
        print node.get_ascii(attributes=["a", "name"])
```

which would print something like this:

```
                     /-aaaaaaaaac
-My annotation, NoName
                    |      /-aaaaaaaaad
                     \NoName
                           \-aaaaaaaaae
```